# Memory leak when deleting a singleton object, cpp

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I don't know why I have a memory leak here and would really appreciate any advice.
Notice that before the process terminates I call destroy(), a static member function that is supposed to delete the singleton object.

Here's the relevant code and valgrind's messaeg:

```
Manager.h:
class Manager {
public:
    // Constructor/destructor
    static Manager * instance();
    static void destroy();
    ~Manager();
        // Bunch of functions that I didn't write here

private:
    Manager();
    static Manager * _singleton; 
        // Bunch of fields that I didn't write here
};

Manager.cpp:
#include "Manager.h"

Manager * Manager::_singleton = NULL;

Manager * Manager::instance() {
    if (_singleton == NULL) {
            _singleton = new Manager();
        }
    return _singleton;
}

void Manager::destroy()
{
    delete _singleton;
    _singleton = NULL;
}

/*
 * Destructor
 */
Manager::~Manager() {
    // Deleting all fields here, memory leak is not from a field anyway
}
```

And here's valgrind's report:

```
==28688== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28688==     in use at exit: 512 bytes in 1 blocks
==28688==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 11 frees, 10,376 bytes allocated
==28688== 
==28688== 512 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==28688==    at 0x4C27297: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28688==    by 0x4014CE: Manager::Manager() (Manager.cpp:33)
==28688==    by 0x401437: Manager::instance() (Manager.cpp:15)
==28688==    by 0x4064E4: initdevice(char*) (outputdevice.cpp:69)
==28688==    by 0x406141: main (driver.cpp:21)
==28688== 
==28688== LEAK SUMMARY:
==28688==    definitely lost: 512 bytes in 1 blocks
==28688==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28688==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28688==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28688==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Why do I have this leak? I do delete `_singleton` in `destroy()`

As I said I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Can it be, that you are calling  'instance()' second time after calling 'destroy()'? In that case memory leak is possible

Comment: You will have to post a small compilable minimalistic code sample which demonstrates the problem. The code you have posted *if used correctly* shall have no leaks, but only *if*, We don't know that unless We see the code.

Comment: Also while destroying, plz check whether _singleton is Null or not before deallocation in destroy() method.

Comment: @undefined `valgrind` does not normally report "definitely lost" if there is a pointer to the memory.  And `valgrind` is reporting that the leak is of memory allocated in the constructor, _not_ in the `new` of `Manager` (although it's hard to know here---I think some compilers may actually do the allocation in a new expression in the constructor).

Comment: @Als: Oh! if it is legal then it is OK to use that. Just thought the way we handle "CloseHandle" API in windows.

Comment: Another possibility could be that you're running multithreaded, in which case your instance() function isn't thread safe, but I doubt this is the case here, because race conditions are hard to reproduce.

Comment: Add the implementation of Manager::Manager() and mark line 33 as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several things to note here.  The most obvious is: when do you
call `Manager::destroy`.  The second thing is that the memory `valgrind`
seems to be complaining about is allocated in the constructor of
`Manager`, which you don't show us.  If we can believe the error message
(and I've generally found `valgrind` to be reliable in this respect,
although it can be fooled), there is no remaining pointer to the memory;
either you're not deleting one of the fields in the object, or the
object allocates memory in its constructor which it doesn't save in a
field.

Finally, it's usually better practice *not* to destruct a singleton.
The whole purpose of the singleton idiom is to avoid order of
initialization issues (in C++, at least—otherwise, just declaring
a static instance of the object is sufficient).  Destructing the object
introduces possible order of destruction issues.  If you don't destruct
it, `valgrind` will warn about possible memory leaks (not "definitly
lost"); you can either ignore the warnings, or filter them out.

Comment: If I don't delete _singleton I'll have a memory leak when the program terminates

Comment: @yotamoo Where?  In a very real sense, there's no such thing as a memory leak when the program terminates; the system will recover all of the memory automatically.  A memory leak is when the program uses more and more memory, the longer it runs, and the memory it uses isn't actually needed.